# How to to disable dragging of a draggable div on drop?

Tags: jquery, draggable

I want to create a `div` which can be `draggable` everywhere but also when i drop it at the other `div`, to not be able to drag it anymore.

I can't find a function for that. I tried with

```
$(".draggable").draggable({ helper: "clone"
```

but no result.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the `dragstop` event on your draggable div, inside the fucntion of that handler you can then remove the draggable functionality. Something like this:

```
$( ".draggable" ).on( "dragstop", function( event, ui ) {

     $( ".draggable" ).draggable('destroy');

} );
```

Likewise you could also include this in the initialization of your draggable div like so:

```
$( ".draggable" ).draggable({
  stop: function( event, ui ) {
      $( ".draggable" ).draggable('destroy');
  }
});
```

If you only want this to happen when it is dropped inside another specific div, not just any time it's dropped, then you would need to put this code inside the handler for the `drop` event of your droppable div....

```
$( ".droppable" ).droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
      $( ".draggable" ).draggable('destroy');
  }
});
```

or

```
$( ".droppable" ).on( "drop", function( event, ui ) {
     $( ".draggable" ).draggable('destroy');
} );
```

**NOTE:** you can achieve the same functionality by replacing:

```
$( ".draggable" ).draggable('destroy');
```

with

```
$( ".draggable" ).draggable('disable');
```

if you plan on making it draggable again in the future with a call to:

```
$( ".draggable" ).draggable('enable');
```